# Check the service running on the port Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Hi like in question I have to check what service is runnning on the connected port.

Code with connection

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the host name or ip address: ");
        String host = scanner.next();

        System.out.print("Enter port: ");
        int port = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());

        try{
            Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
            System.out.println("Connection to host: " + host + " port: " + port + " works.");
            
            // check the service
            
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection to host: " + host + " port: " + port + " does not work.");
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

The hostname or IP address is provided by the user and the program needs to check if the port is running and if so what service is running on the port. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: And? Where are you having problems with? Do you get an error etc? Please provide more information

Comment: so you are basically asking  how to write `nmap`?

Comment: do you have any specific services in mind? to detect what is running on the other side of your connection, you can only parse, what the server is sending to you, or try to provoke a response by sending something.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your question whether there are other systems such as firewalls involved in the network, which would make significant difference in the solution and approach. However, from top of my head I can think about two ways:

1. Using RMI
2. Using Telnet / SSH clients

Now, if the possibility of having another application running on the machines that you want to connect with is out of scope, then RMI might not work.

If the other machine can support SSH please try using [J2SSH](https://github.com/sshtools/j2ssh-maverick) or similar that can literally run your commands on the other machine's terminal and bring you back the output to process.

Say for example, if you run 'netstat' or similar you can get the ports listening as out put and parsing it can help you to understand its status.

I hope this helps to think in the right direction. Thanks.